# Flask and Certbot

Tags: python, apache, flask, certbot

I am getting an error when trying to secure a Flask website with Certbot. I do not receive the following error on a normal site but when running Certbot on a Flask `sudo certbot --apache`
 site I get:

Failed authorization procedure. example.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/j7Q5mIX-Cmk9wevuSQxxfBV5KBBgyQuoG9HXUEbU2Gw:

I am running Apache on Ubuntu 18.04 and Python2.7